# Woocommerce - How to alter product category name with hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I try to alter category name with hook. My problem is that I import from a CSV file, bad encoding category. (not on my side, so I can't do nothing).

The best solution I saw, is to alter the category name by id.

Each time I will import the file, the category with bad name will be re-created.

So I have to let him wrong but display him well at least on front.

Can we achieve this ? I don't find any hook for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found that renaming the name without changing the slug allows me to change the name without being impacted by my importation !

Problem solved !